# Is there a way I can pass the context using return redirect in Django?

Tags: python, django

I wanted to pass the context using `return redirect` since using `return render` will send the post again when refreshing the page.

This is my code for my return render:

```
context = {
        'file_path': file_path+'reviews_processed.csv',
        'file_name': 'reviews_processed.csv',
    }
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Processing done!')
    return render(request, 'vlookup/vlookup.html', context)
```

and this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
# return redirect(vlookup, context)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use django [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/messages/) or [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/) for showing your **custom context or message after successfully redirect**. somethings will be like that

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Processing done!')
return redirect('your redirect page url')
```